# How do I draw polygons around a center point in python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapes, python-turtle

i want to define this function such that the user can input any number of sides, length and coordinates. The problem im facing is that I want the coordinates to be the center of the polygon, not the corner but Im unsure how. Below is my current code

```
import turtle

WIDTH,HEIGHT= 1200,700
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH,HEIGHT)

def draw_polygon(x,y,sides,length):
    pen=turtle.Turtle()
    pen.hideturtle()
    pen.speed(-1)
    pen.penup()
    pen.setpos(x,y)
    pen.pendown()
    for i in range (0,sides):
        pen.fd(length)
        pen.right(360/sides)

while True:
    s=int(input())
    l=int(input())
    draw_polygon(0,0,s,l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The turtle starts drawing from it's set position, since you're drawing clockwise this means the given position will always be the top-left corner of the polygon. To make the position you pass into the function the center you have to offset the turtle starting position.

[Offset example for pentagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYHpW.png)

The offset on the x-axis will always be half the length of one side, approaching zero as the polygon approaches a circle.

The offset on the y-axis will be the radius of the polygon.

In your code replace your set position to offset the turtle start position accordingly.

```
from math import pi

startPosX = x - length/2
startPosY = y + length * sides / (2*pi)
pen.setpos(startPosX,startPosY)
```

On a sidenote you can add:

```
turtle.Screen().exitonclick()
```

in the end of drawPolygon() instead of your while loop to keep the screen up after you've entered your values.